# What does $'\r' mean?

Tags: bash

I came across the following line of code ([*source*](https://svn.mcs.anl.gov/repos/ZeptoOS/trunk/BGP/packages/busybox/src/networking/httpd_post_upload.txt)):

```
IFS=$'\r'
```

I'm not quite sure how to interpret that line (specifically why there is a `$` character before the newline). It seems like the "special variable" named `IFS` is being set to a variable named "the newline character"?

What does this line do, and what part of Bash allows this?

Answer (score 1):

`IFS=$'\r'` set `IFS` variable to carriage return.

`bash` allows [ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) string. `$'string'` will expands to *string*, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

Comment: How is that different from just doing `IFS="\r"`?

Comment: @iqa `IFS="\r"` sets `IFS` to the two-character string backslash, r. `IFS=$'\r'` sets it to a one-character string, a carriage return.

Comment: @Gilles: oh, I only think in case double quotes, maybe I'm too sleep, thanks.

Comment: @Gilles Argh, I keep mentally picturing strings in Bash the way they are treated in ECMA-based languages. I need to stop doing that.